# remove data values and x,y axis from line chart - chartjs react

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm using chartJs line chart for my react application. It has shown the data values(65, 59, 80 etc in my chart) on the line chart. Is it possible to remove or hide those values?

[image]

here is my code

```
const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '',
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56],
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        fill: false,
        pointStyle: 'hidden', // Hide data points on the chart
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false, // Remove x-axis grid lines
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false, // Hide x-axis labels
        },
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false, // Hide x-axis labels
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: false, // Hide data values on hover
      },
    },
  };

<Line data={data} options={options} />
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

`hidden` is not a valid option for the [Point Style](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-styles).

You should use the boolean `false` to disable them:

```
const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: '',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56],
            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            borderWidth: 2,
            fill: false,
            pointStyle: false // Hide data points on the chart
        },
    ],
};
```

Comment: it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it's working for me

```
plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: false,
    },
```